Querying Solr data using tool in standalone mode
I have set up Solr as standalone. When trying to query the data using DB Visualizer and SQuirreL SQL, it prompts for a Zookeeper connection (Solr Cloud). However, I need a tool that can query Solr in standalone mode. Can you suggest one?
I attempted to connect to Solr in standalone mode using DB Visualizer and SQuirreL SQL, but encountered an error:

Unexpected Error occurred attempting to open an SQL connection. class java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Could not connect to ZooKeeper localhost:30505/ within 15000 ms


How to resolve this issue? or recommend a tool for connecting to Solr in standalone mode?

What do you want this tool to do? What are you actually looking for? You can use Solr's admin interface to run queries manually if you need to.

As MatsLindh mentioned your best best might be the built-in Solr Admin UI: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/getting-started/solr-admin-ui.html

Thank You,
But, I'm looking for a tool that can query Solr data similar to how SQL queries are used in relational databases.
